# ¿Como saltar la primera fila y columna al insertar un csv en mariadb con python?

Tags: mysql, python, csv, mariadb

Tengo el siguiente código, que inserta datos de un archivo .csv en una base de datos de MariaDb.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='',
db='mydb')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(file('datos.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(names, \
      classes, mark )' \
      'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', 
      row)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que se salte la primera fila y columna del archivo?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saltarte la primera columna, puedes crear una nueva fila que contenga todas las columnas menos la primera:

```
row = row[1:]
```

Para saltarte la primera fila puedes usar un booleano:

```
first = true
for row in csv_data:
    if first:
      first = false
      continue
    cursor.execute(/* ... */)
```

Todo junto:

```
first = true
for row in csv_data:
    if first:
      first = false
      continue

    row = row[1:]
    cursor.execute(/* ... */)
```

Comment: ¡Funcionó bien!

Solo agregar que modifiqué la linea 'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', por 'VALUES(%s, %s, %s)', porque me daba conflicto en las comillas al intentar agregar los datos.

Gracias @eferion .